# Django CSRF verification failure

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm having issues implementing a button in Django that logs the user out (I'm contributing to an existing project, which unfortunately does not yet use the existing Django auth model)

I have a view (which was existing):

```
def logout(request)
    request.session.flush()
    return render_to_response    ('tcore/logout.html',     
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and a button in base.html

```
<form action = 'logout/' method = 'post'>
{%csrf_token%}
<input class ='formGo' type  = 'submit' value='logout' style = 'float:none:'>
</form>
```

When I try to use the button, I get Forbidden: 403. CSRF Verification failed. Request aborted.

Thoughts?

Comment: Aren't you missing an `%` on the line `{%csrf_token}`?

Comment: Also, there is a syntax error after the `render_to_response` call.

Comment: Oops, thanks, that was a copy/paste error when I put my question on stack overflow; it is there in my code. I'll fix it, thanks!

Comment: Check `POST` data sent through dev tools of your browser to see if the csrf_token is really sent with the form.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to use `RequestContext` **not** in `logout` view, but in the view, which renders `base.html` template.

If template's context does not contain `csrf_token`, the `{% csrf_token %}` template tag does nothing instead of rendering hidden CSRF input field, which may look like this:

```
  <input type="hidden" value="4cEL0P1bToqoOhZL3CLRUFqxIWHWcnnf" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
```

You can use `RequestContext` or manually generate the CSRF token and add it to template's context (as stated in the [Django CSRF documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it)).